# How to remove a number from MySQL's JSON array?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

If I have a MySQL table with a JSON column called `numbers` and a record that has `[1, 2, 3]` in that column (array of integers), how do I update that record to remove the `2` (so it becomes `[1, 3]`)?

Comment: Do you want to do that using query or using any scripting language like PHP or Python

Comment: Doing this with code is not a problem; I'm looking for an sql-only solution as the set is huge.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was searching for an answer my self and came to this question, not wanting to use objects I continued the search. But I found a solution, you need to use a combination of `json_remove` and `json_search`

The following removes the value 1 from the table `tbl` and the column `numbers`

```
UPDATE tbl
SET numbers = JSON_REMOVE(
  numbers, replace(json_search(numbers, 'one', 1), '"', '')
)
WHERE json_search(numbers, 'one', 1) IS NOT NULL
```

1. `json_search` returns the path of where the value is, ie. `"$[0]"`
2. `replace` remove the `"` otherwise an error will occur with `json_remove`
3. `json_remove` will remove the path from the `json_search` result

Et voila, your value is removed.

*Note: this assumes no duplicate values*

Comment: Nice. Thanks for contributing.

Comment: Keep in mind that JSON_SEARCH won't find integer number if in numbers you store integer values (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79316).

Comment: You can use JSON_UNQUOTE instead of replace https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote

Comment: @MKroeders I am pondering a way to fix the duplicates issue here as well. `json_search` can return an array of all matches, and `json_remove` can have 2-n parameters of paths to remove. Now to think of how to write it to where it expands the array to multiple items... hmm...

Comment: @amaster don't know a way directly, after a bit of testing. I think creating your own function using repeat (https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure/mysql-repeat-loop/) and then looping over it until no key is found is your safest bet

Comment: Instead of `replace()` you can use `json_unquote()`.

Comment: @MKroeders, Have you ever tried doing this for multiple values? `all` instead of `one`. If so, please let me know.

Comment: We have a json object stored in the column, and inside that we have the array like mention in question. How can I use tweek this answer for that situation.

Comment: This answer is not working and it's wrong. json_search is not working with integers.

Answer (score 6):

Until someone finds a better solution, I just converted it to an object instead: `{"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3}`. Yes, this is uglier and occupies more disk space, but you get the benefit of not having to worry about duplicates.

To add a number:

```
update tbl set numbers = json_insert(`numbers`, '$."4"', 4);
```

To remove a number:

```
update tbl set numbers = json_remove(`numbers`, '$."4"');
```

To get the row with a certain number:

```
select * from tbl where json_contains_path(`numbers`, 'one', '$."4"');
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way,

```
 JSON_SEARCH(json_doc, one_or_all, search_str[, escape_char[, path]
 ...])
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search

just **search_str**