# How to remove an element from MySQL's JSON array inside an object?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table "tbl1" with a JSON field "numbers" containing values like this:

{ "start" : ["101","102","104"], "final" : ["102","105","106"] }

How can i update "numbers" to remove a specific element (i.e. "102") from "start" and "final" ?

I know i have to use a combination of JSON_REMOVE and JSON_SEARCH but i don't find the solution.

Comment: No sorry. I want to delete only one element from a property value and not all the property.

Comment: Misread your question, but this should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497905/how-to-remove-a-number-from-mysqls-json-array

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.30

Comment: I find a solution with a query like this:
update tbl1 set numbers = JSON_REMOVE(numbers, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(numbers, 'one', '102',NULL,'$.start'))) where JSON_SEARCH(numbers, 'one', '102',NULL,'$.start') is not null;

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT JSON_REMOVE(json_field, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(json_field, 'one', '102'))) json_field
         FROM source_table
         UNION ALL
         SELECT JSON_REMOVE(json_field, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(json_field, 'one', '102'))) json_field
         FROM cte
         WHERE JSON_SEARCH(json_field, 'one', '102') )
SELECT json_field
FROM cte
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(json_field, 'one', '102') IS NULL;
```

and respectively

```
UPDATE source_table
JOIN (  WITH RECURSIVE
        cte AS ( SELECT id, JSON_REMOVE(json_field, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(json_field, 'one', '102'))) json_field
                 FROM source_table
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT id, JSON_REMOVE(json_field, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(json_field, 'one', '102'))) json_field
                 FROM cte
                 WHERE JSON_SEARCH(json_field, 'one', '102') )
        SELECT id, json_field
        FROM cte
        WHERE JSON_SEARCH(json_field, 'one', '102') IS NULL
     ) processed USING (id)
SET source_table.json_field = processed.json_field;
```